# Inverse Functions (Discrete Math)

Tags: functions, inverse

Say you have $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x,y) = (2x+y, y)$

How would you check if the function was invertible? As well as determining it's inverse if it is?

Thank you

Comment: When is a function said to be invertible ? Use the definition.

Comment: When it's one-to-one and onto?

Comment: That's a linear map. Obtain the corresponding matrix and invert it.

Comment: @CenaMaine You are right that a function is invertible if and only if it is one-to-one and onto i.e. your function must be a bijection.

Comment: We haven't learned how to obtain it's matrix yet to invert it

Comment: Ok, then do it by hand. Injectivity first. Assume that $f(x,y) = f(a,b)$. What then?

Comment: @KingTut, ok, so I check if my function is a bijection first, and if so how would I find the inverse?

Comment: For the inverse, take $(a,b)\in Z$ (what's $Z$, by the way?) and find $(x,y)\in Z$ such that $2x+y = a$ and $y = b$.

Comment: Z being all the integers neg. to pos.

Comment: @Friedrich Philipp So I just choose any value in Z for (a,b) and find (x,y) values that will give me those a and b values?

Comment: And you know it never hurts to *work in particulars* first to get a feel for things. Can you solve $f(x, y) = (2, 5)$? How about $f(x, y) = (-10, 12)$, etc. (Also, your domains and codomains are really $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$).

Comment: Thank you, also if it is ℤ^2 x ℤ^2, and say you have (2x+y, -y) instead, since it's squared, that means it's only the positive integers right? therefore not injective?

Comment: The notation I wrote just means the function takes and gives *pairs* of integers. A function $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ would only take and give single integers.